# ViewPager2 FragmentStateAdapter's createFragment Not Invoked in Kotlin Compose Integration

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewpager2, fragmentstateadapter

Within my Android app, I utilize Android's ViewPager2 in conjunction with Kotlin and Compose. Initially, everything functioned seamlessly until the integration of Compose. Now, upon returning to the particular fragment containing ViewPager2, I've encountered an issue. Specifically, the createFragment function within the FragmentStateAdapter of ViewPager2 is no longer invoked when isSaveEnabled is set to true. What is the root cause of this problem and would appreciate guidance on resolving it programmatically. How can I address this issue in my code?

```
binding.viewPager.apply {
    this.adapter = adapter
    offscreenPageLimit = sections?.size ?: 0
    isSaveEnabled = true
}
if (sections?.size!! < 2) {
    binding.tabs.visibility = GONE
    binding.viewPager.isUserInputEnabled = false
} else
    TabLayoutMediator(binding.tabs, binding.viewPager) { tab, position ->
        tab.text = sections[position].name
    }.attach()

@InternalSerializationApi
class HomeGroupTabAdapter(
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
    lifecycle: Lifecycle,
    private val sections: ArrayList<Section>
) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentManager, lifecycle) {
    override fun getItemCount() = sections.size

    override fun createFragment(position: Int) = HomeGroupTabFragment.newInstance(sections, position)
}

@Parcelize
data class Section(
    @SerializedName("code")
    val code: String,
    @SerializedName("items")
    val items: List<Item>,
    @SerializedName("name")
    val name: String
) : Parcelable

@Parcelize
data class Item(
    @SerializedName("type")
    val type: String,
    @SerializedName("code")
    val code: String?
) : Parcelable
```

I tried to set **`isSaveEnabled`** to false; however, when returning to the fragment, the **`createFragment()`** function is called, but the scroll position is not remembered.

Comment: When you restore the saved state, the fragments that were saved are restored for you. Why would you expect brand new fragments (without any restored state) to need to be created via calls to `createFragment`?

Comment: Before integrating Compose, the navigation function operated seamlessly, with the createFragment function being invoked consistently. I also added code to restore the scroll position. However, post-integration, createFragment is only triggered when isSaveEnabled is set to false. Unfortunately, this change has resulted in the loss of scroll position and the transition animation.